# SQL Server select with count query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server. What I want to do is to group families with the total number of members.

[image]

to get something like this

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried?  There is more than one possible approach.

Comment: Enter text rather than images

Comment: i dont know how to have it like text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff     i tried but not getting the result as I post, can mention one of them ?

Comment: Just break the name into first name and last name, then a simple group by on last name.

Comment: It is called a keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `case when` expression with `Aggregate` function

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name like '%tayson%' then 1 end) as tayson,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN name like '%ross%' then 1 end) as ross,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN name like '%dee%' then 1 end) as dee
FROM T
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef5de/2

**Results**:

```
| tayson | ross | dee |
|--------|------|-----|
|      3 |    3 |   1 |
```

Comment: Why would this get an anonymous downvote? downvoter,Is there any reason?  It even has a SQL Fiddle that shows it working.

Comment: i didn't DV it but i think the reason is because if we have multiple distinct lastnames then we will have to write case when for each and every family name. What I mean to say is that it's not generic... But I amnot sure. Let the downvoter reply.

Comment: @G.Arima . . . That would be a really bad reason for a downvote, given that the OP provided explicit data and results, and this solves the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As I mentioned, I am just guessing,not sure about the reason. The actual reason can be given by the downvoter.

Comment: this is exactly the result i want to get

Comment: this is useful answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

Just separate the last name and count using `group by`

```
select substring(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, len(name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1)) as lastname,count(*) as total
from your_table
group by substring(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, len(name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1));
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: it worked too, thank you my friend, but i voted for the one below because i read his answer first, by the way i appreciate it man

Comment: you can accept 1 and can UpVote more than one answers, in case it helped you.

Comment: @ahmed Happy to help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7848561/g-arima   just did it

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to split the names into two columns, (first name and last name) if the names are separated by a space (e.g. Mike Tyson) then you could do something like this :

```
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1) AS FirstName,     
       SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) + 1, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ', name)) AS LastName 
FROM yourTable
```

This will gives you :

```
| Firstname | Lastname |
|-----------|----------|
|      Mike |   tayson |
|      John |     ross |
|    Oliver |   tayson |
|     Aaron |      dee |
|    Robort |     ross |
|      Jack |     ross |
|     Honry |   tayson |
```

Now, use this to count the total members according to their last name.

```
SELECT 
    LastName,
    COUNT(FirstName) AS TotalMembers 
FROM (
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1) AS FirstName,     
       SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) + 1, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ', name)) AS LastName  
FROM yourTable
) D 
GROUP BY LastName
```

this gives you :

```
| LastName | TotalMembers |
|----------|--------------|
|      dee |            1 |
|     ross |            3 |
|   tayson |            3 |
```

Now, you need to use `PIVOT` to rotate the rows into columns :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1) AS Firstname,     
       SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) + 1, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ', name)) AS Lastname 
FROM yourTable
) D 
PIVOT
(
COUNT(FirstName)
FOR  Lastname IN (tayson, ross, dee)
) AS pvt
```

this gives you :

```
| tayson | ross | dee |
|--------|------|-----|
|      3 |    3 |   1 |
```